# Solaris 11 nlsadm list-timezone issue

Tags: solaris, locale, timezone

```
nlsadm list-timezone
iconv_open(wchar_t, UTF-8) failed for 'en_GB.ISO8859-15' locale
Invalid argument
```

What is the cause for this error and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

As iconv was complaining about the en_GB.ISO8859-15 locale, I thought i would try the more generic "C" in its place.

`export LC_ALL=C`

This allowed the command to get past the error and create a timezone listing.

I Suspect the problem with using en_GB.ISO8859-15 is to do with iconv not understanding or liking certain characters or layouts.

Comment: Instead of resetting your locale for the current session, you might simply set it just for the command: `LC_ALL=C nlsadm list-timezone`